# Parse xml with html to through c# web api

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

This is my xml (a bit shortened):

```
<document stored_search_id="11826309" id_site="184569" id_article="86428" hidden="false" position="1" equalgroup="3597146365">
    <unix_timestamp>1548924770</unix_timestamp>
    <header matches="false">
        <text>Mobilstrul för Tele2 - problem ringa 112</text>
    </header>
    <short_header matches="false" length="251" removed="0">
        <text>Mobilstrul för Tele2 - problem ringa 112</text>
    </short_header>
    <summary matches="false">
        <text> Samhälle Kunder i hela landet har rapporterat problem med mobiltelefoni med operatörerna Tele2 och Comviq. Användarna har dålig eller ingen täckning och varken samtal eller internet i mobilen fungerar.</text>
    </summary>
    <short_summary matches="false" length="957" removed="94">
        <text> Samhälle Kunder i hela landet har rapporterat problem med mobiltelefoni med operatörerna Tele2 och Comviq. Användarna har dålig eller ingen täckning och varken samtal eller internet i</text>
    </short_summary>
    <body matches="false">
        <p>
            <text>Enligt Joel Ibson, kommunikationsansvarig på Tele2 började problemen vid tretiden på natten.</text>
        </p>
        <text>  </text>
        <p>
            <text>Det var en omfattande, rikstäckande störning. Den blev snabbt bättre, men det finns fortfarande problem, framför allt i Göteborgsområdet.</text>
        </p>
    </body>     
</document>
```

And this is the object that i want to parse it to:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "document")]
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "unix_timestamp")]
    public long UnixTimestamp { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "short_header")]
    public ShortHeader ShortHeader { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "summary")]
    public Summary Summary { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "short_summary")]
    public ShortSummary ShortSummary { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see my body is of type string but in the xml it is some html.

I post the xml from a file:

```
   var contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
                var httpContent = new StringContent(contents, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                var resoponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, httpContent);

                File.Move(file, file.Replace(folderPath, $@"{folderPath}\Done"));
```

to my api method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task SearchResult([FromBody] SearchResultDataContract searchResult)
{
```

But whenever i have my body as part of the SearchResultDataContract object it can't parse the xml and therefor it will become null.

So i guess it is trying to parse Body as xml instead of a string/html and then if fails. So my question is, how can i parse the body html to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() to encode the string and return it back to html by HttpUtility.htmlDecode()

```
string htmlString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<p>Some text</p>");
htmlString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlString);
```

Comment: Where do you expect me to do that? Since the object isn't parsed to the controller method if the xml doesn't correspond with the object its supposed to be parsed to? :)